# Knockout and DataTable and custom data binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatable, knockout.js

In ASP.NET MVC Project I am using Knockout and DataTable for data binding,

I add data to table like that:

```
    <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: {data: customerList, dataTableOptions: tableOptions}">
       <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: customerName"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: creationDate"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: transType"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But in my case the customers list, each item contains sub list called skillsList
So, I want to add data to table like that:

```
    <tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: {data: customerList, dataTableOptions: tableOptions}">
       <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: customerName"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: creationDate"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: mainSkill"></td>
       </tr>
       
       foreach(var skill in skills) 
       {
          <tr>
             <td data-bind="text: customerName"></td>
             <td data-bind="text: creationDate"></td>
             <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
             <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
             <td data-bind="text: skill"></td>
          </tr>
       }
       
    </tbody>
```

So, In the second **tr** the data is repeated but last **td** will contain skill instead of main skill

I hope you understand what I need

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I would be trying something like this,

```
<tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: {data: customerList, dataTableOptions: tableOptions}">
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: customerName"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: creationDate"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: mainSkill"></td>
   </tr>
   <!-- ko dataTablesForEach: {data: skills, dataTableOptions: tableOptions}

      <tr>
         <td data-bind="text: customerName"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: creationDate"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: skill"></td>
      </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: But it is comment not code !! how this comment run as code ?

Comment: They're called [virtual elements](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).